# browserify circular dependency: something is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browserify, commonjs

I've recently started writing CommonJS modules but facing issues in requiring modules. Why is storage.js unable to reach the example module which I have required? What is the proper way to require a dependent module in this case?

*EDIT: Included more information because the previous question omitted hello.js, which I thought wasn't the cause of the problem. Seems like including it causes a uncaught type error. Also, this is part of the code for a chrome extension, and main.js is the content script.*

```
// main.js
var hello = require('./hello');
var storage = require('./storage');
var example = require('./example');

storage.store(); 

// storage.js
var example = require('./example');
module.exports = (function() {

    function store() {example.ex();}

    return {store: store};

})();

// example.js
var storage = require('./storage');

module.exports = (function() {
    function ex() {
         console.log('example');
    }    
    return {ex: ex};    
})();

// hello.js
var example = require('./example'); // <<<< Including this gives Uncaught TypeError: example.ex is not a function
module.exports = (function() {
    function hello() {
        console.log('hello');
    }

    return {hello:hello};
})();
```

Comment: Is `var storage` in global scope?

Comment: Just pasted your code as is (only inserted in functions console output for checking what was called), and everything works fine, without any errors

Comment: Same as @dajnz. Do you have any browserify or webpack overrides in your package.json or in dotfiles?

Comment: For browserify I've only transform - browserify-shim, nothing else

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but Browserify will wrap in a self-invoking function for you. You can simplify your lib files:

```
// main.js
var storage = require('./storage');
storage.store();
```

Because you don't use `hello` or `example`, don't require them.

```
// storage.js
var example = require('./example');
function store() {example.ex();}
module.exports.store = store;
```

No need to go through the self-invoking function here.

```
// example.js
module.exports.ex = ex;
function ex() {
    console.log('Example');
}
```

This doesn't use `storage`, so don't include it.

`hello.js` does nothing but trigger the circular dependency, remove it.

---

In your updated code, you have a circular dependency between `storage.js` and `example.js`. Because you don't use anything from `storage` in `example`, you can just remove that require. I still think you should remove the self-invoking functions, as that's already part of commonjs.

When loading a module, Commonjs will only execute the file a single time. Everything on `module.exports` is then cached for future calls. When you include the circular dependency for the first time, the module loader sees that its currently being loaded, and you don't get any results back. Subsequent calls will complete as normal.

Comment: code updated. Left out some important information previously